# Mod rewrite rules for passing parameters

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

htaccess file to redirect as follows:

pagename.com/foo -> pagename.com/index.php?view=foo

and it works code in htaccess is

```
RewriteRule ^foo$ index.php?view=foo [L]
```

but I would like to use parameters as well. so it would look this way

pagename.com/foo?parameter1=bar -> pagename.com/index.php?view=foo&parameter1=bar

what I habe created is:

```
RewriteRule ^foo\?([^-]+)$ index.php?view=foo&$1 [L]
```

but it is not working properly - I am redirected to view foo but parameter is not passed

any ideas? thank you in advance

EDIT:

```
RewriteRule ^foo/?([^-]+)$ index.php?view=foo&$1 [L,QSA] 

RewriteRule ^foo/?$ index.php?view=foo [L,QSA]
```

both used separately and with

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

could not get it

EDIT 2:

got another rewriterule for the same foo page - just added QSA to the first as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^foo$ index.php?view=foo [L,QSA]
```

and it works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that RewriteRule only matches `REUQEST_URI` without a query string.

You just need `QSA` flag for this purpose:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^foo/?$ index.php?view=foo [L,QSA]
```

QSA - (Query String Append) is used for appending existing query string with the new ones.

Comment: added as you suggested and it didnt work - i will add edit in question in a second

Comment: found it - got another redirect to the same foo before and it was the one which blocked solution - see edit 2

Comment: Key parts here are the `?$` at the end and `[L,QSA]` flag